# K non-intersecting diagonals in a polygon

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Given a regular **N-sided polygon**, how many **ways** can you draw **K non-intersecting diagonals**?
Any pair of diagonals must not intersect strictly inside the polygon.

---

For e.g. N = 4 and K = 2 -> 2 ways

[image: Quadrilateral polygon and 2 non intersecting diagonals]

---

N = 5 and K = 2 -> 5 ways
[image: Pentagon and 2 non intersecting diagonals]

---

N = 5 and K = 3 -> 0 ways

Comment: For $K=1$ the answer is $\frac{N(N-3)}2$; for $K=N-3$ the answer is the Catalan number $\binom{2N-4}{N-2}/(N-1)$. Those are the easy cases. The other cases look hard.

Comment: Your first example shows $K=1$, not $2$

Answer (score 3):

The answer is $$\frac{1}{K+1}\binom{N-3}{K}\binom{N+K-1}{K}.$$ For a reference, see OEIS here: https://oeis.org/A033282

This apparently comes from the closed form for the $f$-vector of the associahedron $R_n$ given by $$f_i=\frac{1}{n-d-2}\binom{n-3}{n-d-3}\binom{2n-d-4}{n-d-3},$$ since the $k$-dimensional faces of $R_n$ correspond to subdivisions of the convex $n$-gon with $(n-3-k)$ non-intersecting edges.

See section 8 "Combinatorics of convex polytopes" here: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/geompol8.pdf